# How to run java console app with android project

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to build a TCP server-client app.
The client is going to represent android devices and they are going to connect to my TCP server which is JAVA Console App.

In my android project, I have added a new module that is java-library.
In addition, I have a module called entities, which contains my models.

Since they are gradle project, I can manage them easily,
but there is a tiny problem.

I cannot run my server app first before android app.
It's just waiting,

But after I try to run firstly android app, I can run my server(my console app).

If I try to run secondly my server app, I have an error like below.

```
Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks:
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 5000) from /:: (port 47240): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is the server app running? I would recommend to NOT run it on Android. Instead run it on a PC and connect to it from within your app using the IP of your PC (which is not localhost/127.0.0.1!).

Comment: Yeah, I realized that it's my fault, I have already change the IP address. It's already running on My Pc as a java console app. I located it in android project because I wanted to use a common module which will contain my models. But in future, I am planning it to put a remote server, do you think will this approach be a big problem ?